# How to use canonical tag? [Upgrading my website to be multilanguage]

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, upgrade

I have a good SE ranked webpage written in dutch(=nl) and I want to upgrade my site to be in french(=fr) too. So I've created subdirectories for NL en FR, but my root/index is now exactly the same as my /root/nl/index page... Is this the good way (thinking about SEO and knowing my root/index has a good rating and my /root/nl/index is my new copy I want to put on my server):

Here is my code:

```
MY FILENAME: root/index.html (= https://mjazz.be/)

<html lang="nl-be">
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mjazz.be/" /> 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="https://mjazz.be/nl/" /> 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-BE" href="https://mjazz.be/fr/" /> 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
MY FILENAME: root/nl/index.html (= https://mjazz.be/nl/)

<html lang="nl-be">
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mjazz.be/" /> 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="https://mjazz.be/nl/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-BE" href="https://mjazz.be/fr/" />
```

Is this correct? Should it be different? Please help me? Thanks in advance!!